# Pause/Resume Httpurl connection while uploading large files - Android

Tags: java, android, http, httpurlconnection

I was able to upload the large files (Tested upto 1.2GB) to server using .setChunkedstreamingmode() using httpurlconnection. I learnt that we have to keep the url-connection live to send the large sized files. The code i used to upload the large sized files is,

```
public static String uploadFileToServer(String filename, String targetUrl) {
        String response = "error";
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        DataOutputStream outputStream = null;

        String pathToOurFile = filename;
        String urlServer = targetUrl;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";

        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024;
        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(
                    pathToOurFile));

            URL url = new URL(urlServer);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Allow Inputs & Outputs
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(1024);
            // Enable POST method
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);

            outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

            String token = "anyvalye";
            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Token\"" + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8" + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Length: " + token.length() + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(token + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

            String taskId = "anyvalue";
            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"TaskID\"" + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8" + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Length: " + taskId.length() + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(taskId + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

            String connstr = null;
            connstr = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"UploadFile\";filename=\""
                    + pathToOurFile + "\"" + lineEnd;

            outputStream.writeBytes(connstr);
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // Read file
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            System.out.println("Image length " + bytesAvailable + "");
            try {
                while (bytesRead > 0) {
                    try {
                        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        response = "outofmemoryerror";
                        return response;
                    }
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                response = "error";
                return response;
            }
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens
                    + lineEnd);

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            int serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();
            System.out.println("Server Response Code " + " " + serverResponseCode);
            System.out.println("Server Response Message "+ serverResponseMessage);

            if (serverResponseCode == 200) {
                response = "true";
            }else
            {
                response = "false";
            }

            fileInputStream.close();
            outputStream.flush();

            connection.getInputStream();
            //for android InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
            java.io.InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();

            int ch;
            StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
            while( ( ch = is.read() ) != -1 ){
                b.append( (char)ch );
            }

            String responseString = b.toString();
            System.out.println("response string is" + responseString); //Here is the actual output

            outputStream.close();
            outputStream = null;

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // Exception handling
            response = "error";
            System.out.println("Send file Exception" + ex.getMessage() + "");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response;
    }
```

Now during my upload process, if i pause the upload and resume, then it is starting from first byte instead of computing the chunks received by server. To overcome this problem, i coded as

```
// Initial download.
    String lastModified = connection.getHeaderField("Last-Modified");

// Resume Upload.
connection.setRequestProperty("If-Range", lastModified);
```

But i am not able to resume the upload process. Can anyone please help me on this issue since i am newly learning this concepts. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Usually, once a server decides that the connection is lost, if the file isn't complete, it will discard the file.

Comment: @rabbitguy Thanks for your prompt reply. In another case, if i pause and resume my upload, then the server has to resume the uploading process right. So, it has to be handled in server side or from client side.

Comment: Pausing it is different because the connection stays open. The server can poll the client and the client responds. Losing your connection is not the same as pausing the upload.

Comment: @rabbitguy Oh thanks mate. I was not aware of it. I have edited my question now

Comment: how are you pausing it?

Comment: @rabbitguy I am also looking for the same code base. Any code base would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If the receiving server supports it, you can use the Content-Range header to identify a resuming upload. The Google-Drive API supports it. If you roll your own, I'd follow the pattern Google uses:

- Begin upload and get a session identifier.
- When upload is interrupted, wait until internet is available to resume.
- When resuming upload, first inquire of the server how many bytes it has received. (*)
- Resume upload with the next byte after the server's status.

(*) Note that when I rolled my own before, I added an encoded response from the server with the last KB of upload, just to verify it wasn't corrupted in transfer. However, I've never, in production, seen a case where a server had received corrupt data.

Comment: "rolled your own"... smoke if you got em!

Comment: @Jeyaprakash  Well i am also looking for the same! Can u please say that how to resume upload with next byte. Is it possible to do like that? Can u please share some code for android on how to achieve that.